# DEBUG trap statement in ksh93 not executed after first run if it contains exit or return statements

Tags: ksh, trap

I was trying to write a simple function that checks if a config file is "sanitized" and safe for sourcing or not. I seemingly got it to work in `bash`, and in `ksh` (Version ABIJM 93v- 2014-06-25) in the first invocation of the function only. This is the watered-down version of the function that still reproduces this bug for me:

```
function sanitized_source
{ 
    typeset source_filename=$1
    (
        #shopt -s extdebug # Need this if using bash
        trap 'if [[ $? != 0 ]]; then return 66; fi' DEBUG
        PATH=.
        set -re
        . "${source_filename}"
    )
}
```

and the config file:

```
cd /root || echo 'what?'
echo 'why is this executed?'
```

How I run it and what I see:

```
% . ./dotfile
% sanitized_source test.conf
ksh: sanitized_source[79]: sanitized_source[1]: cd: restricted
% sanitized_source test.conf
ksh: sanitized_source[79]: .[1]: cd: restricted
what?
why is this executed?
```

The intent of the `trap` is to cover cases where `set -e` won't exit the shell even if a command failed. From `man bash`:

> **[set] -e**
>
> [...]
>   The shell does not exit if the command that fails is [...] part of any command executed in a && or || list except the  command  following the  final && or || [...]
>
> **extdebug**
>
> [...]
>   2. If the command run by the DEBUG trap returns a non-zero value, the next command is skipped and not executed.

I noticed the parameters `.sh.command` and `.sh.subshell` got changed between the first and second invocations:

```
% sanitized_source test.conf
ksh: sanitized_source[9]: sanitized_source[1]: cd: restricted
% echo "${.sh.command}"
echo 'what?'
% echo "${.sh.subshell}"
0
% sanitized_source test.conf
ksh: sanitized_source[9]: .[1]: cd: restricted
what?
why is this executed?
% echo "${.sh.command}"     
`���2
% echo "${.sh.subshell}"    

%
```

Also, if I replace the `return` or `exit` statement in `trap` with `echo`, for example, I can see that the `trap` statement is then executed every time.

So why is this behavior only observed in `ksh` and not `bash`? What is the root cause and how do I fix it?